# Как правильно говорить: кремы или крема, тренеры или тренера и т.д.?

Tags: орфоэпия

Торт**ы** или т**о**рты, кремы или крема, тренеры или тренера, тракторы или трактора, в аэропорте или в аэропорту, деньг**а**ми или д**е**ньгами.

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с behemothus во всём, кроме "торт**ы** ": НОРМА- т**о**рты, в ЕГЭ часто встречается торт**ы** как ошибка.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо огромное!!! Это опечатка! Т**о**рты, конечно. Неужели до Вас никто не заметил? У меня и язык бы не повернулся сказать торт**ы**

Answer (score 1):

Т**о**рты
кремы, профессиональное и просторечное - крем**а**
тренеры,
тр**а**кторы и трактор**а** (равновозможно),
в аэропорту,
деньг**а**ми и д**е**ньгами (равновозможно, второй вариант - историческая норма, сейчас устаревает)

Пользуйтесь словарями в сети, например тут
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/